# Maximum Likelihood Estimate for Multinomial Logistic in Python's Statsmodels

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels, scipy-optimize, mle

I'm trying to emulate the python's statsmodels implementation of MNLogit just to understand it better and i can recreate the log-likelihood function which matches the scores reported on some fake data.

```
np.random.seed(100)
N = 1000
mu = [0,0]
rho = 0.1
cov = [[1, rho], [rho, 1]]

# u is N*2
u = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, 1000)
x1 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(N,2)) #np.random.rand(N,2)
x2 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(N,2)) #np.random.rand(N,2)

U = -1 + -3*x1 + 4*x2 + u

y = np.zeros(shape=(N, 2))
y[:,0] = ((U[:,0] > 0) & (U[:,0] > U[:,1]))
y[:,1] = (U[:,1] > 0 & (U[:,1] > U[:,0]))

W1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':x1[:,0], 'x2':x2[:,0]})
W2 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':x1[:,1], 'x2':x2[:,1]})

y_full = np.ones(shape=(N*2,1))
class_1 = np.where(((U[:,0] > 0) & (U[:,0] > U[:,1])), 'class_1', 'class_0')
class_2 = np.where((U[:,1] > 0 & (U[:,1] > U[:,0])), 'class_2', 'class_0')
y_full = np.append(class_1, class_2)
W_full = sm.add_constant(W1.append(W2)).reset_index(drop=True)
mn_logit = sm.MNLogit(y_full, W_full)
mn_logit_res = mn_logit.fit()
mn_logit_res.summary()
```

which gives me a reasonable fit the original parameters in my fake data

[MNLogit Results from statsmodels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMCeO.png)

If i write out the negative likelihood function and use the scipy minimize function i can recover the same log likelihood (1260.8) but the parameter estimates differ.

```
def cdf(W, beta):
    Wb = np.dot(W, beta)
    eXB = np.exp(Wb)
    eXB = eXB /eXB.sum(1)[:, None]
    return eXB

def take_log(probs):
    epsilon = 1e-20 
    return np.log(probs)

def calc_ll(logged, d):
    ll = d * logged
    return ll

def ll_mn_logistic(params, *args):
    y, W, n_params, n_classes = args[0], args[1], args[2][0], args[3]
    beta = [params[i] for i in range(0, len(params))]
    beta = np.array(beta).reshape(n_params, -1, order='F')
    
    ## onehot_encode
    d = pd.get_dummies(y, prefix='Flag').to_numpy()
    
    probs = cdf(W, beta)
    logged = take_log(probs)
    ll = calc_ll(logged, d)
    
    return -np.sum(ll)

n_params = 3, 
n_classes = 3
z = np.random.rand(3,3).flatten()
#probs = ll_mn_logistic(list(z), *[y_full, W_full, n_params, n_classes])


res = minimize(ll_mn_logistic, x0 =z, args =(y_full, W_full, n_params, n_classes), 
             options={'disp': True, 'maxiter':1000})
res
```

[Results from Scipy's minimize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx7ov.png)

I suspect the differences are due to the optimisation methods applied in statsmodels but i've tried a bunch from scipy and none of the results are even close to the results returned from statsmodels using the hessian and the jacobian. Can anyone explain how to better approximate the statsmodel's approach using scipy's minimize?

Comment: Great question!
I suggest you include in your questions the specific values you are talking about. I know you included screenshots. The outputs look different, and I can't quickly see what you are talking about. Now, I'll go see if I can help find an answer or where to find it.

Comment: Take a look here
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/ad4b474b712517515400b0447998c6771897e02d/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py#L2206

Comment: you have 6 parameters in the statsmodels version but 9 parameters in yours

Comment: the optimized value of the negative loglikelihood is the same in both versions

Comment: Thanks Vincent, i've updated the question to include the negative loglikelihood which appears the same in both. 

Josef yes, i think that's expected. Typically the MLE is estimated for n classes by estimating n-1 regressions and inferring the third. Not entirely sure why the statsmodel summary object neglects reporting the third class but i fed in the same data e.g. y_full, W_full which have 3 classes represented.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Because the multinomial MLE algorithm fits all but one of the class regressions, when i pass in the parameters for each of the three classes I need to "zero" out one of the 3 parameters sets that scipy optimises over.

```
def cdf(W, beta):
    Wb = np.dot(W, beta)
    eXB = np.exp(Wb)
    eXB = eXB /eXB.sum(1)[:, None]
    return eXB

def take_log(probs):
    epsilon = 1e-20 
    return np.log(probs)

def calc_ll(logged, d):
    ll = d * logged
    return ll

def ll_mn_logistic(params, *args):
    y, W, n_params, n_classes = args[0], args[1], args[2][0], args[3]
    beta = [params[i] for i in range(0, len(params))]
    beta = np.array(beta).reshape(n_params, -1, order='F')

    #This step ensures that we're only fitting two parameter sets.
    beta[:,0] = [0, 0, 0]
    
    ## onehot_encode
    d = pd.get_dummies(y, prefix='Flag').to_numpy()
    
    probs = cdf(W, beta)
    logged = take_log(probs)
    ll = calc_ll(logged, d)
    
    return -np.sum(ll)

n_params = 3, 
n_classes = 3
z = np.random.rand(3,3).flatten()
#probs = ll_mn_logistic(list(z), *[y_full, W_full, n_params, n_classes])


res = minimize(ll_mn_logistic, x0 =z, args =(y_full, W_full, n_params, n_classes), 
             options={'disp': True, 'maxiter':1000})
res
```

Which gives us the expected parameter values for the other two classes.

[The correct parameters found using scipy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5WfW.png)